# jquery custom event in ajax success callback not working without settimeout

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, callback

I have the following jquery ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                        
     // Without setTimeout, the triggerHandler doesn't work
     setTimeout(function (e) {                           
         $(this).triggerHandler($.Event("CustomEvent"));
     });
  }
});
```

And in another location:

```
$(this).on('CustomEvent', function (evt) {
  alert("CustomEvent");
});
```

The above code displays an alert. However, if I do not enclose the **triggerHandler** call in **setTimeout** the .on is never invoked and an alert is not displayed. Any idea(s) why the setTimeout appears to be necessary for this to work?

Comment: Posting the complete js code will be helpful... or a minimal working example

Comment: I'd assume it's due to the scope of `this` not being whatever you expect it to be within the `success` handler of `$.ajax`

Comment: try putting into `complete` function of your ajax.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan very true, `this` seems to be `window` object which is the one executing the timeout function, but `this` is another different thing in the scope of `success` function

Answer (score 0):

The reason is "this" is not always "this".

If the `setTimeout` method works, your event is on `$(window)`, so this should work:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                        
    $(window).triggerHandler("CustomEvent");
}
```

There is no need to create a jQuery-Event-object by the way.